# How to print a window without displaying url on header

Tags: javascript, css, vb.net, printing-web-page

I want to print a window using javascript like

```
        function printWindow() {
        window.print();         
    }
```

But it is printing with **url** and date time at top and bottom. like 
[image: the image]. There is an option in firefox to not dispaly the title and url on File=>Page Setup
[image]. If I select blank from browser, it will not dispaly url and title. But I want to do this from my code even in javascript or vb.net.Some body are telling to use

```
<style type="text/css" media="print">
@page 
{
    size: auto;   /* auto is the initial value */
    margin: 0mm;  /* this affects the margin in the printer settings */
}
```

but it is still displaying the url. How can I achieve this. Thank you

Comment: I don't think you can control those print settings from JS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to print without url and datetime by javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5360158/how-to-print-without-url-and-datetime-by-javascript). And [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5353479/print-page-without-url-and-datetime-using-javascript?rq=1).

Answer (score 0):

This is browser-specific. You can't modify it using javascript or css. The only way to hide this url link is to change the browser settings.

Comment: I have mentioned that answer in my question itself

Comment: Oh yea, sorry for this